# Installing a another Sails.js version locally

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js

I've installed [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org) version `0.9.13` globally on my Mac which runs fine, but I'm trying to fiddle with the `0.10.0-rc4` locally in a folder.

Running `sudo npm install sails@beta` seems to work fine; my **node_modules/package.json** says `"version": "0.10.0-rc4"`

But when I run `sails new testProject` in that folder, the generated **testProject/package.json** says `"sails": "0.9.13"`.

I know that I could just change the **testProject/package.json** to `"version": "0.10.0-rc4"` and then `npm install` but that doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong? How could I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you can just run

```
./node_modules/sails/bin/sails.js new testProject
```

instead of `sails new testProject` once you have installed rc4 in some 'parent' folder.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a virtual environment like [nave](https://www.npmjs.org/package/nave). It will help you not to disturb your existing installations.

Sequence would go something like this:

```
npm install nave -g
nave use <envname> stable
$npm install sails@beta -g
```