# What is the cleanest way to switch between two versions of Sailsjs (0.12.X & 1.0.X)?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Currently have sailsjs 0.12.X install globally as a npm package.
I want to be able to write and maintain sails-js projects using both 0.12.X and 1.0.X version.

is there a solution similar to NVM for nodejs that would work for sails-js ?

Comment: Hi @user2206021 this might give you a good place to start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609546/installing-a-another-sails-js-version-locally

Comment: Thanks @Raqem - I used nave to create a virtual env and was able to install/use different nodejs and sailsjs version (in subshell) without affecting my other projects.